# I want to Store Data in React

Tags: reactjs, database

I want to Store Data in React so Data will show even if the page is refreshed I have some inputs and I have saved their value in the state using useState but now I want that the data will show even if the page is refreshed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of solving this is to use your browser's local storage to store data and get them when the component is rerendering inside the componentDidMount.

This is how to store data in localstorage.

```
handleFormSubmit = () => {
  const { user, rememberMe } = this.state;
  localStorage.setItem('rememberMe', rememberMe);
  localStorage.setItem('user', rememberMe ? user : '');
};
```

This is how to retrieve them.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const rememberMe = localStorage.getItem('rememberMe') === 'true';
  const user = rememberMe ? localStorage.getItem('user') : '';
  this.setState({ user, rememberMe });
}
```

For further details refer https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/localstorage-react/.